# How do I make this plot have a x axis that increments from 0 to 19?

Tags: python

## Plotting the Cumulative Summation of the Explained Variance

```
plt.figure(figsize(15,12))
plt.plot(np.cumsum(pca.explained_variance_ratio_))
plt.xlabel('Number of Components')
plt.ylabel('Variance (%)') #for each component
plt.title('Churn Dataset Explained Variance')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xticks function like this:

```py
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 19, step=1))
```

Reference this to learn more about plt.xticks - 
https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html